# SQL finding and replacing the null with a trigger

Tags: t-sql

I have been trying to create a trigger that will find the nulls in the DateAdded column and replacing them with the current date or with GETDATE(), and I seem to be writing a lot of lines when it seems like it would be simple, is an after update the right way to go?

```
USE MyGuitarShop;
    GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Products_INSERT') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER Products_INSERT;

GO

CREATE TRIGGER Products_INSERT
    ON Products
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

  IF EXISTS (SELECT DateAdded FROM Inserted WHERE DateAdded = Null)
        UPDATE Products SET DateAdded = getDate() WHERE dateAdded IS NULL
GO...................
```

INSERT into Products(DateAdded, ProductCode,ProductName, Description, ListPrice)
VALUES (NULL, 'halter', 'Hofner Icon', '', 699.99);...........this works but whenever I try and update the statement and I go back into the edit screen, everything is added but the new row I added is null under the dateadded, how do I get it to auto update to the date after the insert? as far as I can see this should have worked (I did change the beginning to after insert, update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work as your `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE Products SET DateAdded = getDate() WHERE dateAdded IS NULL
```

Comment: this works but whenever I try and update the statement and I go back into the edit screen, everything is added but the new row I added is null under the dateadded, how do I get it to auto update to the date after the insert? as far as I can see this should have worked (I did change the beginning to after insert, update

Comment: I'd recommend using the other answer and updating the default in value

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could make the DateAdded column NOT NULL and add a default constraint of GETDATE(). That way, whenever a row is created and DateAdded is not given a value, it will be set to the current date:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Products
  ALTER COLUMN DateAdded datetime NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR DateAdded;
```